# Facebook open graph don't show the og:title from metas

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to share an some url from my site facebook don't scrap the title I put in og:title but something else.
Example on this URL :

http://tenden.fr/page/content/16910/socialtotal-24hour-13-30-alla.php#alla

The og title is :"Top 50 des cosplay les plus drôles ou les déguisements de héros qui ne se prennent pas au sérieux (et ça fait du bien)"

And the title that Facebook pick is "**18283 partages** Top 50 des cosplay les plus drôles ou les déguisements de héros qui ne se prennent pas au sérieux (et ça fait du bien)"

Please help me find wher does this "18283 partages" came from. I must have done something wrong but after hours, could not find it.

Comment: Your OG meta tags seem OK, no errors/warnings in debug tool, and according to “See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL” they are alright too. Looks like this is actually taken from the page content – because you have that as text content (displayed on top of the image), followed by the exact “Top 50 des cosplay …” text.

Comment: My guess would be that perhaps Facebook goes looking for a suitable title in the document content itself, because you specified the exact same value for the OG title and the OG description – which doesn’t make the most sense to begin with. Try with a proper title, that is significantly different from the description.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests it seem like Facebook Parse elements from the page HTML when I use the "#alla" anchor, but when I suppress it in the og:url tag,  Facebook show the title I put in the og:title tag.

I know this is strange. And you response CBroe help me think again as I was stuck.Thanks